# Cpu and memory utilization is high in Aix

Tags: kernel, aix, kernel-parameters

**Hello everyone,**

I have problem with my **CPU utilization** I am using sar command to know my cpu idle % in that idle percentage is null and **%sys %usr** utilizing more, I am trying to check with **topas,ps and nmon** utilities there are no process utilizing **CPU** but my cpu idle percentage is null. If I use **topas** to see the high CPU utilizing process it displaying topas utilizing max cpu. Output:

**Cpu Utilization**

**topas**

```
Topas Monitor for host:********                                     
Wed Sep  9 12:46:45 2015   Interval:2         

Kernel   84.60  |########################    |    
User     15.40  |#####                       |  
Wait      0.00  |                            |  
Idle      0.00  |                            |  
Physc =   0.06                    %Resc=  7.61  

Network    BPS  I-Pkts  O-Pkts    B-In   B-Out
Total    1.79K    3.00    3.00   1.39K   403.0

Disk    Busy%      BPS     TPS  B-Read  B-Writ
Total     0.1    48.0K    3.00       0   48.0K

FileSystem          BPS    TPS  B-Read  B-Writ
Total              499K  136.0    499K       0

Name           PID  CPU%  PgSp                
topas      20578344 72.5 3.58M                
BESClien    7143678 24.8 6.11M                
java       27328718  0.8  178M                
oracle     13762772  0.3 3.94M                
oracle      7274508  0.3 3.97M                
oracle     18874506  0.2 10.4M                
oracle     10551546  0.2 4.05M                
oracle     11337746  0.2 10.4M
oracle      7077936  0.1 8.47M
oracle     11927742  0.1 6.46M
oracle      7602366  0.1 11.5M
oracle     16580770  0.1 8.47M
sshd       22675700  0.1 1.12M
xntpd       9175168  0.1  524K
oracle     18546864  0.1 18.9M
oracle     24182924  0.0 36.3M
nmon_aix   24051748  0.0 3.16M
oracle     19595324  0.0 7.19M
oracle     17825850  0.0 3.66M  
oracle     25493590  0.0 7.70M
```

**SAR Output**  sar 1 5

```
13:02:49    %usr    %sys    %wio   %idle   physc   %entc
13:02:50      11      89      -       -     0.08    10.2
13:02:51       7      93      -       -     0.08     9.9
13:02:52      15      85      -       -     0.08     9.9
13:02:53      65      35      -       -     0.22    26.9
13:02:54      12      88      -       -     0.07     9.2

Average       33      67      -       -     0.10    13.1
```

**nmon**

```
 CPU-Utilisation-Small-View qqqqqqqqqqqEntitledCPU=  0.80 UsedCPU= 0.295qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
 Logical  CPUs              0----------25-----------50----------75----------100                     
 CPU User%  Sys% Wait% Idle%|           |            |           |            |                     
 0  11.6  18.7   0.0  69.7|UUUUUsssssssss        >                          |                     
 1   5.5   1.5   1.0  92.0|UU             >                                 |                     
 2   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|    >                                            |                     
 3   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|    >                                            |                     
 EntitleCapacity/VirtualCPU +-----------|------------|-----------|------------+                     
 EC  12.1  12.2   0.2  12.4|UUUUUUssssssiiiiii-------------------------------|                     
 VP   9.7   9.8   0.2   9.9|UUUUssssiiii-------------------------------------|                     
 EC=  36.9%  VP=  29.5%     +--Capped---|------------|-SMT=4-----100% VP=1 CPU+                     
 Memory qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
      Physical  PageSpace |        pages/sec  In     Out | FileSystemCache                     
 % Used       99.1%     11.3%  | to Paging Space   0.0    0.0 | (numperm) 23.3%                     
 % Free        0.9%     88.7%  | to File System  172.4    1.0 | Process   58.5%                     
 MB Used   24361.7MB    57.7MB | Page Scans        0.0        | System    17.4%                     
 MB Free     214.3MB   454.3MB | Page Cycles       0.0        | Free       0.9%                     
 Total(MB) 24576.0MB   512.0MB | Page Steals       0.0        |           ------                    
                          | Page Faults     377.2        | Total    100.0%                     
 ------------------------------------------------------------ | numclient  0.0%                     
Min/Maxperm     705MB(  3%)  21138MB( 90%) <--% of RAM       | maxclient 90.0%                     
Min/Maxfree     960   1088       Total Virtual   24.5GB      | User      77.5%                     
Min/Maxpgahead    2      8    Accessed Virtual   17.8GB 72.5%| Pinned    22.2%                     
                                                         | lruable pages     6012560.0           
Top-Processes-(163) qqqqqMode=3  [1=Basic 2=CPU 3=Perf 4=Size 5=I/O 6=Cmds]qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
 PID       %CPU     Size      Res     Res      Res     Char    RAM      Paging         Command    
        Used       KB      Set     Text     Data     I/O     Use   io   other repage           
25821292     9.0    93220   134592   128536     6056       14    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
14876786     7.6     6280     6492      740     5752        1    0%      0      0      0 topas_nmon
7143678     1.2    19152    22380    16128     6252       99    0%    176      0      0 BESClient 
19136722     0.3    92628   134000   128536     5464       94    1%      0     203      0 oracle    
     0     0.0      384      384        0      384        0    0%      0      0      0 Swapper   
27328718     0.0   182628   182680      128   182552        0    1%      0      0      0 java      
7274508     0.0    91228   132600   128536     4064        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
13762772     0.0    91200   132572   128536     4036        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
16449756     0.0    93044   134416   128536     5880        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
7602366     0.0    98924   140296   128536    11760        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
11337746     0.0    97816   139188   128536    10652        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
24182924     0.0   124348   165720   128536    37184        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
19857490     0.0    94096   135468   128536     6932        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
18874506     0.0    97836   139208   128536    10672        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
16580770     0.0    95836   137208   128536     8672        1    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
11927742     0.0    93784   135156   128536     6620        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
9175168     0.0      712      780      256      524        0    0%      0      0      0 xntpd     
22675700     0.0     2164     4256     3104     1152        2    0%      0      0      0 sshd      
18546864     0.0   106488   147860   128536    19324        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
24051748     0.0     3440     3764      532     3232        0    0%      0      0      0 nmon_aix53
15269924     0.0   109204   150576   128536    22040        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
13434942     0.0     2052     2320     1268     1052        0    0%      0      0      0 sendmail  
6488076     0.0      380      392       36      356        0    0%      0      0      0 syslogd   
17825850     0.0    90916   132288   128536     3752        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
8650866     0.0      512      528       56      472        0    0%      0      0      0 cron      
19595324     0.0    94524   135896   128536     7360        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
14811336     0.0     1732     1772      116     1656        0    0%      0      0      0 vmstat    
3735760     0.0    90884   132256   128536     3720        0    1%      0      0      0 oracle    
12779648     0.0     6972     7480     1048     6432        0    0%      0      0      0 rmcd      
4718734     0.0    28004    36132    22752    13380        0    0%      0      0      0 tnslsnr   
6684926     0.0    13256    13924     2084    11840        0    0%      0      0      0 nsrexecd
```

How can I  reduce cpu utilization?

Comment: Your nmon output differs from your topas output; are you still seeing an issue?

Comment: @jeff schaller yes we are facing issue,we are not sure which we have to consider and main thing this server is  in wpar.

Comment: You can always try `netpmon` and then `trcstop` for having detailed CPU process utilization.